# python pillow package does not work in Rstudio

Tags: python, r, keras, python-imaging-library

I'm using windows 10. I have installed keras and it works. I have also successfully installed the python pillow package through the console, yet the following code does not work in R Studio:

```
library(keras)
library(imager)
mystery <- image_load("./mystery.jpg", target_size = c(224,224))

Error in image_load("./mystery.jpg", target_size = c(224, 224)) : 
  The Pillow Python package is required to load images
```

But, as I said, I have installed pillow in my command console and I checked the installation

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

Can anyone help me make it work?

Comment: See here https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/64

Comment: That helped me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My computer ran Python 3.8, Anaconda ran Python 3.6. I changed my PC's Python to 3.6 and that fixed the problem.